# Parameterized Insert Query with method value

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have two methods. When I call the method glass, I need to insert the value in a query. How can I insert the value of a method in a query?

I'm working with MVC, C# and SQL Server.

The code I tried: in this method call a method glas

```
RController re = new RController();
re.Glas(C_E);
string insert = "INSERT INTO dbo.MEP (R1) VALUES (@code)";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insert, con))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", "HERE METHOD GLAS");
    con.Open();
    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Method GLAS returns a string. That string is what I need to insert in a query. The query is located in another controller method (Rcontroller).

```
public void GLAS(string C_E)
{
     // more code
     if (i > 0)
     {
          string glas1 =  "OK";
     }
     else
     {
          string glas1 = "Fail"; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current method is `void` and not returning any value. You may pass the value by ref, or just simply change your method to return value:

```
public string GLAS(string C_E)
{
     //more code
     string glas1 = "OK"; 
     if (i > 0)
     {
          glas1 =  "OK";
     }
     else
     {
          glas1 = "Fail"; 
     }
     return glas1;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", GLAS(C_E));
```

Also, it is advised not to use `.AddWithValue` and you may use `Parameters.Add()` instead like:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GLAS(C_E);
```

Comment: when I put the return in that place it gives me error, it does not recognize the variable glas1

Comment: do exatly as what i did, you must define glas1 before the if and assign it inside if, you have defined it insde if, so it can't be used outside if scope.

Comment: thnks ,my mistake, I'll deal with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on this subject, you have several choices.  Some of them have already been elaborated upon.  The following approaches exists, `Add`, `AddWithValue`, and an entire parameter collection.  This provides flexibility, but also you mention to return a value.

So to approach the initial parameter aspect.

- Add: You define the parameter, the type in SQL, and value.  This alleviates potential database inference issues.  You pass a value which is an integer but SQL believes it should be a decimal as defined.
- AddWithValue: SQL will auto infer the type, simply pass a value and parameter.
- Parameter Collection:  You define all of your parameters in advance, then simply pass to your `SqlCommand`.

A sample method would be:

public class DatabaseContext : IDbRepository
{
     private readonly string dbConnection;

```
 public DatabaseContext(IConfiguration configuration) => dbConnection = configuration.GetConnectionString("dbConnection");

 public bool Insert(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
 {
      // If no parameters, then you really are not inserting.  Handle exception.

      using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
           using(var command = new SqlCommand(connection, query))
           {
                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                return (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0);
           }
 }
```

So in essence you would call your context, pass the query, the parameters, then execute your query.  But you have it returning a boolean, rather than a conditional check to assign a success or failure.  When you call, you would know it succeeded, so you could pass a valid status code back ie `HttpStatusCode.Ok`.

But you could also wrap in a factory, or clean the approach a bit when interacting.  Hopefully this helps.